# Redux Middlware Response Handler Strategy

Tags: redux, middleware, multilingual

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/) *Middleware* receives a response at some time. **Which is the most canonical strategy?**

- Continue with *Action*, not waiting for asynchronous response. Response
  handler will dispatch a new *Action* cycle when called.
- Make *Middleware* freeze *Action* until response arrives, and dispatch it further to *Reducer* from response handler.
- Make a flexible *Middleware* that allows both variants.

In other words: **Can *Middlware* dispatch new *Actions*, or only proceed to *Reducer* with current *Action***?

Answer (score 0):

The middleware signature is `({ getState, dispatch }) => next => action` and it's really up to you when to call next and what to dispatch.

For redux there's really no problem if this is after an async operation, but it can lead to unexpected behaviour. For example, if the redux router middleware actions are not dispatched directly, your state will be behind the current state of the website. So as rule of thumb, only take messages that are of interest to the middleware and always pass through the rest synchronously.

And yes, redux middleware can dispatch new actions.

Also please note that the reducers will be handled after the middleware has run (this is the last function to run in the middelware chain).